# Client side pageLoad doesn't get new input values after updatePanel partial postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm having trouble reading a server-side set value from an input, after an UpdatePanel partial postback

This is the simplest example I can use to reproduce the issue:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSrc" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                 OnTextChanged="txtInput_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:Panel>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDst" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOutput" runat="server" />
            <a id="lnkTest" href="#" onclick="pageLoad();">check txtOutput</a>
        </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var txtOutput = $('#<%=txtOutput.ClientID%>');

    function pageLoad() {    
        var exe = $(txtOutput).text();    
        alert(exe);
    }

</script>
```

Server side, I'm just putting txtInput text reversed into txtOutput:

```
protected void txtInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt = string.Empty;

    for (int i = txtInput.Text.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        txt += txtInput.Text[i];
    }

    txtOutput.Text = txt;
}
```

Client side, pageLoad() is executed after every partial postback, but txtOutput value is never updated: it's always the same of the first load (empty, in this case)

I tried also with getInstance().add_endRequest but no success

I would expect that 'exe' contains the actual value of txtOutput.Text, set server side, but it's not so

Clicking lnkTest, the same function is invoked with the expected result

Sorry if I'm doing something wrong, this is my first post

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script should be like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad() {
            alert($('#txtOutput').val());
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: txtOutput is a runat server control, so I need to use the clientId or a class; however, jQuery selector works like a charm: if I click the link, the same function is executed with the expected result

Comment: how does that make a difference if the textbox is server control? you are anyways using the ID on the client side using JQuery..

Comment: it depends upon clientIDMode; anyway I've edited 'cause I missed to point out that the selector works: if you click a.lnkTest, the same function is invoked and it works as expected

Comment: well, it wasn't solved yet but you put me on the right direction: putting 'var txtOutput = $('#<%=txtOutput.ClientID%>');' into 'pageLoad()' body makes things works, so there's something related to ajax lifecycle that must be updated

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of issues.

First, you are doing the jQuery selector twice.  Once when setting the var txtOutput and then again in the pageLoad method when setting exe.  You only need one.  The example below eliminates the second - you could go the other way and have txtOutput be just the control ID instead of the actual control object.

Second, you need to reference the value of the 1st element of the selected object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var txtOutput = $('#<%=txtOutput.ClientID%>');

    function pageLoad() {
        var exe = txtOutput[0].value;
        alert(exe);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: yes, this is a simplification of my original code: in fact, I could have write directly $('#<%=txtOutput.ClientID%>').text() here; but that's not the point: as you can see, the a.onclick calls the same function which works as expected

Answer (score 0):

@Karthik Ganesan put me in the right direction, I'll report the final code for convenience of others

```
function pageLoad() {

    var txtOutput = $('#<%=txtOutput.ClientID%>');
    var exe = $(txtOutput).val();

    alert(exe);
}
```

only if `var txtOutput = $('#<%=txtOutput.ClientID%>')` is **inside the pageLoad body**, it works even when invoked by ajax's lifecycle; I still don't get why, though

You can, of course, use static selectors like '#txtOutput', depending on clientIdMode and fx version, and leave it out